# Mexican visa for Taiwanese person while travelling

Tags: visas, applications, mexico, taiwanese-citizens

Are there any embassies in South or Central America where a visiting foreigner (in particular, a Taiwanese national) could apply for a Mexican tourist visa?

The embassy in São Paulo for instance is unsuitable as they will only issue visas to residents of Brazil.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not qualify for a visa exemption?

Comment: Yes: [Países y regiones que requieren visa para viajar a México](https://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-requieren-visa-para-mexico/)

Comment: You don't have an APEC Business card, nor any of those visas?

Comment: Did you actually talk to the embassy in São Paulo? They might have more flexibility than their published requirements indicate, especially if you have a good reason why you couldn't get it in Taiwan. Another approach would be to get a visa for a country whose visas are accepted for tourist entry to Mexico (ie, any Schengen country, UK, US, Canada, or Japan).

Comment: @MichaelHampton We didn't know about APEC, thanks, but unfortunately don't have one of those nor are aware of any other such available options.

Comment: @krubo We did indeed go and speak to the embassy and it was they who told us that they only grant visas to residents. Thanks for the tip re: getting a visa for the US, etc. - that looks like the best option (returning to Taiwan would be possible but onerous and expensive!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, the answer is No.

According to https://www.mexicocity.com/v/visa-requirements/ proof of permanent residency in the country where the application is being made is required to apply for a tourist visa.

Comment: Thank you - not the answer I was hoping for but it appears to be definitive!